# How to `synchronized` on "MapEntry" of Scala `TrieMap`?

Tags: multithreading, scala

I would like to update the value `vold` of a `TrieMap` `t` for some key `k` iff the new value `vnew` some predicate `p(vold, vnew)` is `true`. Since values can be modified through multiple threads, a `synchronized` block is needed. The code could `t.synchronized` but that would block updates to other keys' values. Is it possible to block only for the key that's actually being updated?

Now that I've written out the question, does it make sense to `t.keySet.filter(_ == k).head.synchronized` (since there's no guarantee that `k` is the same instance of the key in `t`)? Is there a more canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Since values can be modified through multiple threads, a synchronized block is needed.

The canonical way of working with `TrieMap` is to use the `replace`/`putIfAbsent`/`remove` methods. Get the old value, calculate the new value, and if `replace` fails, repeat.

Looking through the API, I don't see anything suitable to do what you want directly, and `t.keySet.filter(_ == k)` has to iterate through the entire `Map`; in most cases I'd expect it to be worse than just locking it (unless you have a lot more threads than entries?).

Comment: After digging a bit more into my specific needs, `replace` will fit them. I'm thinking a `replaceIf` shouldn't be too difficult and would fit others' potential needs. Would you know how to submit RFE's to Scala?

Comment: I think it _would_ be difficult: `replace` uses compare-and-swap operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) which has special hardware support, and I don't think there is any equivalent which `replaceIf` could use.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. OTOH, the alternative is for the coder to do it themselves and, as we've seen, synchronizing on the key isn't very feasible for the coder but should be trivial from within the `TrieMap` function.

Comment: Hmm, looking through `TrieMap.scala`, it's not as trivial as I had first thought.

Comment: What do you think of the `replaceIf` implementation below?

Answer (score 0):

If `p` satisfied the following conditions:

- antisymmetry (ie `p(v0, v1)` implies `!p(v1, v0)` and `!p(v0, v1)` implies `p(v1, v0)`)
- transitivity (ie `p(v0, v1)` and `p(v1, v2)` implies `p(v0, v1)`

The following can be implemented (WARNING: the code below is untested):

```
def replaceIf(key: K, newvalue: V)(predicate: (V, V) => Boolean): Option[V] = {
  val oldvalue = replace(key, newvalue)

  if (oldvalue == None || predicate(newvalue, oldvalue.get)) {
    oldvalue
  } else {
    replaceIf(key, oldvalue.get)(predicate)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is completely subject to data races. Say you have `oldValue` and Thread 1 wants to replace it with `newValue1` and Thread 2 wants to replace it with `newValue2`. Both `predicate(oldValue, newValue1)` and `predicate(oldValue, newValue2)` are false, so both should fail and leave `oldValue` in place. Thread 1 replaces `oldValue` (line 3), while it's calculating `predicate(oldValue, newValue1)` on line 7 thread 2 executes line 3 and replaces `newValue1` with `newValue2`. It checks `predicate(newValue1, newValue2)` and reports success. And you've got the wrong result.

Comment: Wouldn't one or the other thread 'win' during the first `replace` call such that one of them will see the other's `newvalue` rather than the existing `oldvalue`?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what causes the problem in the example I gave.

Comment: I've simplified the implementation.

I don't see the problem. One thread can replace the `oldvalue` then another thread can replace `newvalue1`. In the current implementation, if the function returns `newvalue`, the caller knows it didn't replace `oldvalue`.

Comment: For this implementation: say `predicate` is always false (it satisfies both of your conditions). You get an infinite loop if the map contains `key`.

Comment: Then there's another property of the `predicate` that's not being stated. I'm thinking it might be part of irreflexivity (ie `!p(v0, v1)` implies `p(v1, v0)`) but I could be misrepresenting irreflexitivity. The gist is that `predicate` should be a function like 'greater than' or 'less than'.

Comment: I think the missing property was antisymmetry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123188/discussion-between-noel-yap-and-alexey-romanov).